# Providing a common viewForHeaderInSection for multiple UITableViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I have several UITableViewControllers which creates the same exact section header. Currently, I have copy pasted the viewForHeaderInSection code in each of the view controllers. But this is a bad practice. I can create a base class which can provide that implementation but I am looking for a better way. The problem with base class is that it will only work with UITableViewController unless I have the base class from UIViewController. If I use UIViewController as base class then most of the view controllers will be getting that functionality even though they dont require it.

How can I solve this problem? I tried Protocol Extensions but you cannot override methods in protocol extensions.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle this is to create a custom `UIView` subclass for your header. Then, in each of your TableViewControllers, you can do this:

```
class TVC: UITableViewController {
    //...
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return MyCustomHeaderView(title: "sometitle", ... )
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: That is what I was doing! But since it was the same custom view I was wondering if there is a better way so I dont have to implement viewForHeaderInSection multiple times.